# onNext not called Retrofit and rxAndroid

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to get values from a web using retrofit and rxAndroid but onNext doesn't called.
Here, my classes:

```
public class ForumService {

private static final String FORUM_SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.104:8080/curso-fullstack/symfony/web";
private ForumApi mForumApi;


public ForumService(){
    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        }
    };

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(FORUM_SERVER_URL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    mForumApi = restAdapter.create(ForumApi.class);

}

public ForumApi getmForumApi() {
    return mForumApi;
}

public interface ForumApi{

    @GET("/video/lasts_videos")
    public Observable<List<Data>> getVideos();

    /*@GET("/posts/{id}")
    public Observable<Post>
    getPost(@Path("id") int postId);

    @GET("/comments")
    public Observable<List<Comment>>
    getComments(@Query("postId") int postId);

    @POST("/posts")
    public Observable<Post> postPost(Post post);*/
}
```

}

```
public class ListPresenter {

ListActivity mView;
ForumService mForum;

public ListPresenter(ListActivity mView, ForumService mForum) {
    this.mView = mView;
    this.mForum = mForum;
}

public void loadPosts() {

    mForum.getmForumApi()
            .getVideos()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Data>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Data> posts) {

                    mView.displayPosts(posts);
                }
            });
}
```

}

And then, I execute the method `loadPosts()` from my activity, to fill a list and display in a ListView. 
If i look about android logs, I can see how retrofit displays to me that found the results, but for any reason onNext is never called.

[image]

Comment: if `onNext` isn't called probably `onError` is called. Add `e.printStackTrace()` to `onError`

Comment: You are trustly, but do not know how to resolve I have the following error, I know what means but I am new with retrofit and rxandroid.
 ERROR: >com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: your model - `List<Data>` does not correspond to the received JSON. You can copy the JSON response to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate the model class for you.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and at the end works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll write an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"Just add this line in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments:

`onNext` wan't been called because there was a problem in the JSON deserialization. `onError` was called instead.